# Ways to describe the structure of polyhedra

Tags: convex-optimization, polyhedra, convex-cone

I'm an engineer working in optimization. As you know, finite, unbounded, real polyhedra are the natural ambient for linear optimization, and much theory is devoted to finding the best solution fast.

Nevertheless, I haven't been able to find a theoretical framework which allows me to "visualize"  the structure of large polyhedra.

I tried to look at the face lattice, for example. Vertices can be easily understood as kind of equivalent solutions, but, for instance, I can't grasp the meaning of two vertex not being part of any 1-dimensional face of the polyhedra, but then appearing later together in a higher dimensional face.

Are there any framework for extracting some kind of structural information out of arbitrary polyhedra ? If you consider the face lattice to be one of them: which properties of it (ie chains, antichains, etc) ?

I'm specifically interested in rational cones.